# How to set up basic authentication for some subdomains but not others using envif

Tags: .htaccess, basic-authentication, .htpasswd

Thanks to some wonderful people here at stack overflow I got my authentication working to demand a password at dev.website.com using this script:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^.*dev\.website\.com$ require_auth=true
AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/website.com/.htpasswd
AuthName "Password Protected"
AuthType Basic
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Satisfy any
Require valid-user
Allow from env=!require_auth
```

I also want it to demand a password on: myname.website.com mynamedev.website.com & devmyname.website.com. Basically on anything but "www.website.com" and "website.com".

What is the simplest way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have thought you could do the following

```
SetEnv require_auth=true
SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^www\.website\.com$ require_auth=false
SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^website\.com$ require_auth=false
AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/website.com/.htpasswd
AuthName "Password Protected"
AuthType Basic
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Satisfy any
Require valid-user
Allow from env=!require_auth
```

The first line setting the default case to be authentication is required, the second two lines being the specific cases where authentication is not required.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
#set env "auth" only for subdomains
SetEnvIfNoCase host ^((?!www\.).+)\.website\.com$ auth=1
 #auth 
 AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/website.com/.htpasswd
 AuthName "Password Protected"
AuthType Basic   

 #Here is where we allow/deny
Order Deny,Allow
Satisfy any
Deny from all
Require user valid-user
Allow from env=!auth
```